# Matlab - How to plot on different y axis

Tags: matlab, plot, double, axis

i would to plot on the same graph the power and torque of an electric motor.
i used a for cycle to plot the delta-star configurations, there is also a double gear system, so i would to plot 2 series of data (Power and Torque) for each configuration.
i tried this but i note that in the second loop it plots in the second axis, and not in the first. i use matlab 2015, so i don't have `yyaxis function`

```
clc; clear all;close all

tau=[8.823;1.604]; %in ordine decrescente
n_gamme=length(tau);
data=[22 22;575 1200;1500 6000;365 175];%P,Ginocchio,rpm max,C
names={'Star';'Delta'};

nN=zeros(2);nmax=zeros(2);M_N=zeros(2); %inizializzo

for i=1:n_gamme %contatore gamme
%     j=1; se non ho stella-triangolo
for j=1:2 %contatore stella-triangolo
    P=data(1); %potenza max
    nN(i,j)=data(2,j)./tau(i); %rpm, ginocchio 
    nmax(i,j)=data(3,j)/tau(i); %giri max
    M_N(i,j)=data(4,j)*tau(i); %coppia max
end    
end

PL=['r','r-';'g','g-'];

%     j=1; %se non ho stella-triangolo
for j=1:2 %contatore stella-triangolo
%         subplot(length(tau),1,j);
%         figure

    x1(j,:) = linspace(0,nN(1,j)); %numero di giri da 0 al ginocchio 1
    x2(j,:) = linspace(nN(1,j),nmax(1,j)); %da ginocchio 1 a max 1
    x3(j,:) = linspace(0,nN(2,j)); %da 0 a ginocchio 2
    x4(j,:) = linspace(nN(2,j),nmax(2,j)); %da ginocchio 2 a max 2

    C_1(1,j)=M_N(1,j); %coppia costante 1 marcia
    C_2(j,:)=30*P*1000./(pi*x2(j,:)); %coppia 1 marcia
    C_3(2,j)=M_N(2,j); %coppia costante 2 marcia
    C_4(j,:)=30*P*1000./(pi*x4(j,:)); %coppia 2 marcia

    ax1 = gca;
    plot(ax1,[0,nN(1,j)],[C_1(1,j) C_1(1,j)],PL(1,j),'LineWidth',2/j^2) %I coppia costante
    hold on
    plot(ax1,x2(j,:),C_2(j,:),PL(2,j),'LineWidth',2/j^2) %coppia I
    plot(ax1,[max(x2(j,:)),nN(2,j)],[C_3(2,j) C_3(2,j)],PL(1,j),'LineWidth',2/j^2) %II coppia costante
    plot(ax1,x4(j,:),C_4(j,:),PL(2,j),'LineWidth',2/j^2) %coppia II
    ylim([0 3500])
    ylabel(ax1,'Torque [Nm]'); %# Add a label to the left y axis
    set(ax1,'Box','off');%# Turn off the box surrounding the whole axes

   axesPosition = get(gca,'Position'); 
   ax2 = axes('Position',axesPosition,...
   'YLim',[0 30],...            %#   and a different scale
   'XAxisLocation','top',...
   'YAxisLocation','right',...
   'Color','none',...
   'XColor','b','YColor','b',...
   'Box','off');                %#   ... and no surrounding box

    hold on
    m=P./nN; %pendenza potenza
    P_1(j,:)=m(1,j).*x1(j,:); %potenza 1 marcia
    P_2(1,j)=P; %Potenza costante 1 marcia
    P_3(j,:)=m(2,j).*x3(j,:); %Potenza 2 marcia
    P_4(2,j)=P; %Potenza costante 2 marcia

    plot(ax2,x1(j,:),P_1(j,:),'b--') 
    plot(ax2,[max(x1(j,:)),nmax(1,j)],[P P],'b--')      
    plot(ax2,x3(j,:),P_3(j,:),'b--') 
    plot(ax2,[max(x3(j,:)),nmax(2,j)],[P P],'b--') 
    ylabel(ax2,'Power [kW]');

    linkaxes([ax1 ax2],'x'); %lega tra di loro gli assi,
    grid on
    grid minor
end
```

How can i plot in the same scale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you use `ax1 = gca`.  `gca` is the current axes, and after you finish the first iteration, the current axes is the second one, since it is the last one you plotted to.

To solve the problem, add before the loop the axes creation `ax1 = axes`, and replace `ax1 = gca` by `axes(ax1)` so that `ax1` becomes the current axes.

NOTE: Notice also that you are creating `ax2` *twice*. This means that that there are actually two identical axes with the exact same locations and properties. A better practice would be to move all axes creation before the `for` loop, and the loop is used only to plot into the them. I would move write the following before the loop:

```
ax1 = axes;
hold on;
ylim([0 3500])
ylabel(ax1,'Torque [Nm]'); %# Add a label to the left y axis
set(ax1,'Box','off');%# Turn off the box surrounding the whole axes

axesPosition = get(ax1,'Position'); 
ax2 = axes('Position',axesPosition,...
   'YLim',[0 30],...            %#   and a different scale
   'XAxisLocation','top',...
   'YAxisLocation','right',...
   'Color','none',...
   'XColor','b','YColor','b',...
   'Box','off');                %#   ... and no surrounding box

hold on;
ylabel(ax2,'Power [kW]');
linkaxes([ax1 ax2],'x'); %lega tra di loro gli assi,
xlim([0,3800]);

grid on
grid minor
```

and the loop is now just this:

```
for j=1:2 %contatore stella-triangolo
%         subplot(length(tau),1,j);
%         figure

    x1(j,:) = linspace(0,nN(1,j)); %numero di giri da 0 al ginocchio 1
    x2(j,:) = linspace(nN(1,j),nmax(1,j)); %da ginocchio 1 a max 1
    x3(j,:) = linspace(0,nN(2,j)); %da 0 a ginocchio 2
    x4(j,:) = linspace(nN(2,j),nmax(2,j)); %da ginocchio 2 a max 2

    C_1(1,j)=M_N(1,j); %coppia costante 1 marcia
    C_2(j,:)=30*P*1000./(pi*x2(j,:)); %coppia 1 marcia
    C_3(2,j)=M_N(2,j); %coppia costante 2 marcia
    C_4(j,:)=30*P*1000./(pi*x4(j,:)); %coppia 2 marcia

    plot(ax1,[0,nN(1,j)],[C_1(1,j) C_1(1,j)],PL(1,j),'LineWidth',2/j^2) %I coppia costante
    plot(ax1,x2(j,:),C_2(j,:),PL(2,j),'LineWidth',2/j^2) %coppia I
    plot(ax1,[max(x2(j,:)),nN(2,j)],[C_3(2,j) C_3(2,j)],PL(1,j),'LineWidth',2/j^2) %II coppia costante
    plot(ax1,x4(j,:),C_4(j,:),PL(2,j),'LineWidth',2/j^2) %coppia II

    m=P./nN; %pendenza potenza
    P_1(j,:)=m(1,j).*x1(j,:); %potenza 1 marcia
    P_2(1,j)=P; %Potenza costante 1 marcia
    P_3(j,:)=m(2,j).*x3(j,:); %Potenza 2 marcia
    P_4(2,j)=P; %Potenza costante 2 marcia

    plot(ax2,x1(j,:),P_1(j,:),'b--') 
    plot(ax2,[max(x1(j,:)),nmax(1,j)],[P P],'b--')      
    plot(ax2,x3(j,:),P_3(j,:),'b--') 
    plot(ax2,[max(x3(j,:)),nmax(2,j)],[P P],'b--') 

end
```

Answer (score 1):

Prior to R2016a you should use `plotyy` for the kind of plots you want to do.

Comment: there is something wrong, i obtain this: http://imgur.com/a/PV4Y7 it is wrong, the data cursor does not match with x axis

Comment: That is interesting and I cannot reproduce this. I assume that the data cursor callback is doing something wrong. You might try to write your own.. Right-click on data cursor and select "Edit text update function".

Comment: Note also, that Lior's answer might give you the more immediate result you are looking for. I am going to up-vote his answer.